# Checking presense of file using fopen in read mode does not given error for . or / filename

Tags: c, linux, file, fopen

I am trying to check presence of a file using `fopen` api. I expect that if `fopen` returns NULL then it means file is not present. I provide `file_name` as an input command line parameter.

My code looks like this:

```
FILE *file = NULL;
file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
if(file == NULL)
{
    /* file is not found */
}
else
{
    /* file is found */
}
```

If I provide . or / as `file_name` then it accepts it as a valid filename and feigns it detected the file. Should not `fopen` be returning NULL in this case on **Linux**?

I tried same thing on **Windows**, where it is working as I am expecting (`fopen` returns NULL).

**Background:**

The user will give path and filename (of an xml file) as the input option to the app which will then validate this option by checking the presence of (xml) file at the specified path.

The user can give any string as a path so `fopen` is good enough to detect it except when user enters . or / - these are of course not required (xml) files - so I was expecting `fopen` will detect it as error and we will report to the user that "File is not found". But, `fopen` accepts them as valid file and when we try to process it there are other series of errors.

Comment: `.` and `/` are also valid files.

Comment: How? There is no such file present - or is there some default file by Linux?

Comment: type `ls -l`. and you will find `.`

Comment: I tried and it showed '.' and '..'. 
'/' was not not shown. What can be the reason of that?

Comment: Also note that `fopen` can return `NULL` if the file exists but could not be opened, for instance due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, that is a good feature of it. I have it in mind and it is also expected.

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood Try passing `-a` to `ls`. By default, the entry `.` is hidden. `/` is the root director.

Comment: What is your problem? Why is it wrong for `.` to be a valid file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` and `/` are directories under Linux, they are not files, but they do exist.

I suggest you `stat` the file first to determine if it exists, AND if it is a normal file and not something else entirely. (like a directory, device or hard-link)

Check the result of stat to determine if the filetype is a regular file.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
attr =  GetFileAttributes(filename)
if (!(attr &= FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {

}
#elif __linux__
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
stat buf;
int ret = fstat (fp, buf);
if ((ret == 0) && (S_ISREG(buf->st_mode))) {
    // This is a regular file, not something 'odd'
}
#endif
```

GetFileAttrubutes reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28VS.85%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Actually I was using stat previously, and it was not returning error for . or / and accepting it as a file (on Windows and Linux both).

That is why I opted for fopen which worked fine on Windows and gave same issue on Linux.

Comment: You need the contents of the stat structure to determine if it really is a regular file. I've added a snippet to explain.

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood Explicit checks for a few paths won't work unless you are prepared to check for thousands of files. How about all the files in the /dev folder (sda, cdrom) that are not regular files? Or any other directory you try to open? `.` `..` and `/` are just 3 examples

Comment: Thanks - I will give it a try.

Comment: @StephenArts `S_ISREG` is available on Linux only? I need a fix which works on Windows and Linux both. Do you have any counterpart of `S_ISREG` for Windows in mind?

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood if you use the MINGW you could include sys/stat.h

Comment: @StephenArts No, we are not using MINGW. :(

Comment: @ZeeshanMahmood Then the solution is to use the GetFileAttributes call, and use #ifdef to switch between the two different platforms.

Comment: @StephanArts - You can improve your answer by adding error checking to your `stat()` call.  As it is now, if the file doesn't exist, your code could very well treat it as a regular file.

Comment: I added "background" in the main question - please read that for better understanding of the context in which this question was asked. Thank you.

Comment: @StephanArts Please first open the file and then use `fstat()` to get information about the opened file or you have a race conditions where someone could exchange the file between checking for its presence and opening it.

Answer (score 5):

On POSIX-compliant systems it is not necessarily an error to open non-hardlink files, *including directories*, in read mode if the permissions allow.

Comment: What is the alternative then?

Comment: The alternative is `stat()`, as given in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

When fopen tries to open a file. It does parsing the file path.

You should know that directory is also a special kind of file in linux.

If you provide only "." (which means present working directory) and
/ means root directory.  So fopen can successfully open those directory. Hence it's not returning NULL>

Comment: `fopen` does not parse the file path in a typical implementation, the operating system does.

Comment: Yes that's true. need to call the open system call. the open system call internally doses everything. But according to the question i made the answer simple. If you really wants to know the details, please go through the kernel open system call.